# Como agrupar elementos de un array en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

Deseo poder agrupar estos elementos de un array, el array contiene lo siguiente:

```
let cells = ['A10', 'B10','C10','D10','A23','B23','C23','D23', 'A40', 'B40', 'C40', 'D40']
```

La idea es que me pueda quedar de esta manera:

```
let cells = ['A10;A23;A40', 'B10;B23;B40','C10;C23;C40','D10;D23;D40']
```

Es decir que el primer elemento se agrupe con el primero que tenga la misma letra y asi sucesivamente.

He estado haciendo muchas pruebas pero aun no lo logro.

https://jsfiddle.net/ShotCraft3x/nort3azx/

Comment: Podrías mostrar alguna de las pruebas que has intentado? que te ha fallado en esas pruebas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes guardar los datos en un objeto, dentro del forEach checo cuál es el primer elemento del string, y dentro del objeto reviso si ya hay un elemento con esa letra, si es así; se lo concateno agregando un ';', si no, lo agrego como el primer elemento para esa letra, después los values del objeto los guardo en la variable group_col

```
let cells = ['A10', 'B10','C10','D10','A23','B23','C23','D23', 'A40', 'B40', 'C40', 'D40']

let index = 5;
let group_col = []
let mask = {}
cells.forEach(val =>{
    if(mask[val[0]]){
    mask[val[0]] += (';' + val)
  } else{
    mask[val[0]] = val
  }
})

group_col = Object.values(mask)
console.log(group_col)
```